# Removing columns according to a list in a file

Tags: awk, cut

I have a problem with removing columns from a file.

`input.tsv`:

```
Otu1    otu2    otu3    otu4    otu5
1   2   5   9   3
8   9   8   4   2
```

I would like to remove a column if its header is listed in file `remove.txt`, e.g.:

```
otu2
otu3
```

So the result would be:

```
Otu1    otu4    otu5
1   9   3
8   4   2
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Example using Perl

removeCols.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $file1="input.tsv";
my $file2="remove.txt";

open RFILE, $file2;
@cols=<RFILE>;

open INPUT, $file1;

#read header line, save indicies
my @header = split( /\t/, <INPUT> );

for my $i (0..$#header){
    if (grep(/$header[$i]/, @cols)){
        push @idx,$i;
        $header[$i] = undef;
    }
}
print join("\t",grep(defined,@header));


# loop remaining file
while(<INPUT>){
    my @line = split(/\t/, $_);
    $line[$_] = undef for (@idx);
    print join("\t",grep(defined,@line));
}
```

command-line run as such:

> prompt> perl removeCols.pl

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I edited my question, I hope it is clearer now